# How to show Progress dialog on custom Dialog?

Tags: android, android-studio, progressdialog

I am getting image from server and showing it on custom dialog and I want to show progress dialog while image is fetching.

I am using this

```
loadingDialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "", "Loading. Please wait...", true);
```

but it Hides under the custom dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in call of fetching an image from server

```
try {
    progDialog = new ProgressDialog(Activity_FindInfo.this);
    progDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    progDialog.setMessage("loading");
    progDialog.setCancelable(false);
    progDialog.show();
} catch (Exception ex) {
}
```

Comment: i am using this loadingDialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "", "Loading. Please wait...", true);  but it Hides under the custom dialog.

Comment: u create a custom dialog view ?

Answer (score 0):

declare this in your class

```
private ProgressDialog progDialog;
```

after that add following code just before call to your fetching image..

```
try {
    progDialog = new ProgressDialog(yourCustomDialog.getContext());
    progDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    progDialog.setMessage("fetching image...");
    progDialog.setCancelable(false);
    progDialog.show();
} catch (Exception ex) {
}
```

then when image is fetched before that add this to dismiss dialog..

```
try {
    if (progDialog != null && progDialog.isShowing()) {
        progDialog.dismiss();
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
}
```

Comment: this way add yourCustomDialog.getContext() to this line progDialog = new ProgressDialog(yourCustomDialog.getContext());